# can "coexist" cover animate and inanimate things?

Tags: meaning

We can talk about different animals, plants, groups of people, and belief systems "**coexisting**," by which we mean not just

> To exist together, at the same time, or in the same place. [definition 1 from [TFD]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coexist)

but

> To live in peace with another or others despite differences [definition 2 from TFD]

Would it be incorrect or confusing to combine these senses and lump living and non-living things together, like this:

> **We need to create sustainable cities where people, animals, plants and resources can coexist.**

Does "resources" not belong?

Comment: ‘Confusing’ may be a bit strong, but it certainly reads as rather _awkward_ and not very natural to me.

Comment: I don't think of myself as *coexisting* with the tar sands.

Comment: @Tromnano: precisely, and neither do I! And the usage of the word with the first sense, simply meaning "existing at the same time," without any connotation of connection or living peaceably, seems strange. Perhaps because if there's no connection, why even mention it?

Comment: There are [about 1,520 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22and+gas+coexist%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books for *[liquid, etc.] and **gas** coexist*. I see nothing wrong with saying "abstract" states of matter and other "inanimate" things *exist* or *coexist*. But OP's usage is something of a [zeugma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma), in that the different referent nouns don't really "[co-]exist" in the same sense.

Comment: I have several times seen discussions of whether two computer programs can "coexist".  The word is often used in what I might (failing to find a better term) call a "metaphorical" sense, giving inanimate objects the characteristics of animate ones.  Eg, one might say (a spur of the moment example) that water and oil "dislike" each other and hence cannot "coexist".

Comment: Yes. Things that are inanimate but still "interact," in the broad sense of the term as its used in chemistry etc.

Comment: It would have been better to say something like "We need to create cities where people, animals, and plants can coexist and share resources in a sustainable way." Resource sharing is part of the equation for coexistence among the living things—but the resources are not, as it were, their own interest group.

Comment: This is a very good question for illustrating some of the (understandable) inadequacies of dictionaries. _To exist together, at the same time, or in the same place. [not used to bracket referents in widely different semantic fields, thus *'Cadwaller Q Groole II coexisted with smallpox']_

Answer (score 1):

Resources can coexist with other things, so it's correct in that regard.

People, animals and plants are the same class of thing in a way resources are not, which makes putting all four nouns on the same level read awkwardly.

People, animals and plants each cannot *not* coexist with resources, as they each need resources to survive, which makes the statement pointless. (You may be thinking of different types of resources in the statement, but it isn't clear).

So while it's not wrong, it's not good either.

Comment: Yes, it's not my sentence, but I believe the writer was thinking of "resources" as in "natural resources," including oil, water, etc. I thought it was an ineffective statement because it attempts to suggest "wise use of natural resources" and "respect for biodiversity" by throwing them all together and saying we need to "coexist."